# Masonry 16 column layout with content spanning 2, 3, 4 or 6 columns

Tags: css, jquery-masonry

I'm using Vanilla Masonry (http://vanilla-masonry.desandro.com) to create a mosaic of photos similar to jean-georges.com

Basically I need to add extra columns, the css out of the box only has 3 columns with fluid widths 16%, 36% and 56%, which I think has 2% padding/margin around the content. I don't want any gutters or padding and need 16 columns so I changed the css to 6.25%, 12.5%, 18.75%, 25%, 31.25% and 37.5%. Remember I want content spanning 2, 3, 4 or 6 columns so the columns aren't all the exact same size. I have changed my images to the correct aspect ratio and size to work together plus I'm using the columnWidth function to return the container/16 and set my columns to that size.

It doesn't seem to work correctly and many of my col6 rectangles are being resized to col4. I don't know what's happening, the photos resize themselves when I resize the window but they haven't kept their size in relation to each other.. It may be a dpi issue, I'm getting the graphics redone this afternoon, however it should still work based on the aspect ratio and telling it how many columns to span.

EDIT: I have got it working for a very specific browser window size, I resized the developers tools and it kind of pushed it up together. I'm wondering if there's some percentage padding/margins getting added but can't find any! Another possibility is the container height is affecting it.

[image: mosaic masonry almost working]